# How to connect other calls after initial twilio call

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to implement something like
First on API call Twilio call my number and when I pick a call it will say "we'll connect your call" and then it connects the destination call

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) to generate the outbound call and then one of the call forwarding approaches below, to point the URL too. The code examples are in the upper right corner of this page.

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)